# search on first letters of phrase - like vscode

Tags: javascript, regex, search

I would like to mimic the command palette search in vscode. I have seen the same search in a few applications, but vscode is where I saw it recently.

I'm not sure if there is a specific name for the type of search I'm looking for, but I'm trying to match a search string to a set of phrases based on the starting letters of each word in the phrase.

Perhaps a few examples can help describe what I would like. They are below the function in comments in my example code.

```
function search(searchTerm) {
        const searchLetters = searchTerm.split('');
        const results = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++) {
            const words = phrases[i].split(' ');
            let matched = true;

            for (let j = 0; j < searchLetters.length; j++) {
                let letterMatch = false;

                for (let k = 0; k < words.length; k++) {
                    if (words[k][0] == null) continue;

                    if (words[k][0].toLowerCase() === searchLetters[j].toLowerCase()) {
                        letterMatch = true;
                        words[k] = words[k].substring(1);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!letterMatch) {
                    matched = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (matched) {
                results.push(phrases[i]);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

const phrases = [
      'Tiny Happy Edward',
      'King of the hill',
      'Off to see the wizard',
      'Orangutan Fond fuel',
      'Clone output',
      'Cloud storage',
      'Compare parts',
      'Comic partitions'
    ];

    console.log(search('the')); // should return ['Tiny Happy Edward', 'King of the Hill'] (the start letter of each word and "the")
    console.log(search('off')); // should return ['Off to see the wizard', 'Orangutan Fond fuel']
    console.log(search('thap')); // should return ['Tiny Happy Edward']
    console.log(search('ted')); // should return ['Tiny Happy Edward']
    console.log(search('thaped')); // should return ['Tiny Happy Edward']
    console.log(search('comp')); // should return ['Compare parts', 'Comic partitions']        
    //now trickier ones that I couldn't get working
    console.log(search('clou')); // should return ['Clone output', 'cloud storage']
    console.log(search('cl ou')); // should return ['Clone output'] and nothing else. The space should force new word.
```

I tried to search for the answer before posting, but it is difficult to find the words. I even tried chatGPT, but it was an uphill battle trying to explain it. C'mon stackoverflow, you can defeat that blasted chatbot!

Further notes:
Each phrase may contain up to 15 words.
The number of phrases could reach 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to do what you're looking for. The idea is to search starting from the first word, when, if failed, backtrack and start from the second word etc until either the search string or the words list are exhausted.

```js
function matchesWords(search, words) {
    if (search.length === 0)
        return true

    if (words.length === 0)
        return false

    let [first, ...rest] = words

    if (search[0] === ' ')
        return matchesWords(search.slice(1), rest)

    return (
        (
            search[0] === first[0]
            && matchesWords(search.slice(1), [first.slice(1), ...rest])
        )
        || matchesWords(search, rest)
    )
}

function matches(search, phrase) {
    return matchesWords(search, phrase.toLowerCase().split(' '))
}


//

const phrases = [
    'Tiny Happy Edward',
    'King of the hill',
    'Off to see the wizard',
    'Orangutan Fond fuel',
    'Clone output',
    'Cloud storage',
    'Compare parts',
    'Comic partitions'
];

let test = [
    'the',
    'off',
    'thap',
    'ted',
    'thaped',
    'comp',
    'clou',
    'cl ou',
]

for (let s of test) {
    console.log(s, phrases.filter(p => matches(s, p)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a lot simpler than my attempt.